# Calculate Experience without overlapping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to come up with the correct query to calculate the employment experience time but, I can't get it right. Here's the data I have:

Case 1:

```
EmployeeID    PoisitionID      StartDate    EndDate
1               15             5/22/2017     5/22/2018
1               17             7/14/2018     8/10/2019
```

Case 2:

```
EmployeeID     PositonID       StartDate    EndDate
1                15            5/22/2017     8/10/2019
1                17            3/8/2019      8/10/2019
```

Case 3:

```
EmployeeID     PositonID       StartDate    EndDate
1                15            5/22/2017     NULL
1                17            3/8/2019      NULL
```

- In the first case, my expected result in months would be: 27 months for both positions.
- In the second case, my expected result in months would be:27 months for positonid 15 and 0 months for positionid 17 because positionid 17 falls during the date range of the first position and therefore, the employee will not be awarded with any years of experience.
- In the third case, my expected result in months would be:30 months using today's date as an enddate for positonid 15 and 0 months for positionid 17 because positionid 17 falls during the date range of the first position and therefore, the employee will not be awarded with any years of experience.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any gaps, so I think this does what you want:

```
select employeeid,
       datediff(month, min(startdate), coalesce(max(enddate), getdate())) as months
from t
group by employeeid;
```

Comment: This should work for case  2 and  3 but, not for case 1 because there's a 1 day of un employment. the first position ended on 5/22 and the second position started on 5/23

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have:

Your table 1:

```
select 1 as EmployeeID     ,               15 as PositonID       ,             cast('5/22/2017' as date) as StartDate,     cast('5/22/2018' as date) as EndDate into t2
union select 1,               17,             '7/14/2018',     '8/10/2019'
```

And the query to get the result

```
with a as
(
    select EmployeeID, isnull(StartDate, cast(getdate() as date)) as sedate from t2
    union
    select EmployeeID,  isnull(EndDate, cast(getdate() as date)) from t2
) 

select a1.*, a2.sedate, case when datediff(month,a1.sedate,     a2.sedate)< 0 then 0 else isnull(datediff(month,a1.sedate, a2.sedate), 0) end as months from a a1 left join a a2 on a1.EmployeeID = a2.EmployeeID and  a1.sedate < a2.sedate 
and not exists(select 1 from a a3 where a3.EmployeeID = a2.EmployeeID and a3.sedate > a1.sedate and a3.sedate < a2.sedate )
```

I changed the table to the values of Case2 and Case 3 and it seemed to work.

Let us know if that helps